# How to replace few characters in string using Hive or Python

Tags: python, json, string, hive

I'm trying to omit few characters to format my string. I have below sample string and would like to replace '/*[1-999]*/' with ','.

I've been using regexp_extract and regexp_replace but nothing seems to work.

`select regexp_extract('/* 1 */{"key1" : "value1","key2" : "value2"}/* 2 */{"key1" : "value1","key2" : "value2"}','\/*\*','%');`

I expect output to be 
`',{"key1" : "value1","key2" : "value2"},{"key1" : "value1","key2" : "value2"}'`

Comment: Use this code `re.sub("(\/\*\s+\d+\s+\*\/)",",",yourstring)`

Answer (score 0):

Try using this [RegexDemo](https://regex101.com/r/C5Wd3j/1)

An example using python:

```
text = '/* 1 */{"key1" : "value1","key2" : "value2"}/* 2 */{"key1" : "value1","key2" : "value2"}'

st = re.sub("(\/\*\s+\d+\s+\*\/)",",",text)
print (st)
```

Output:

```
,{"key1" : "value1","key2" : "value2"},{"key1" : "value1","key2" : "value2"}
```